# How to export particular table schema and data using ora2pg migration?

Tags: oracle, postgresql, migration, ora2pg

I'm using ora2pg migration tool for migrate table schema and data from ORACLE database to Postgres Database.

Using the following query, I can export the entire schema and data from the ORACLE database and Import the data into Postgres Database.

To export database schema:

```
./export_schema.sh
```

To export data:

```
ora2pg -t COPY -o data.sql -b ./data -c ./config/ora2pg.conf
```

Import the exported data using this:

```
./import_all.sh -d MyDB -o postgres(Owner) -U User
```

But I've no idea, how to migrate a particular table schema and data using this.

Anybody knows about it, answer.It helps me a lot. Thanks in advice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to migrate some specific tables, yo have do some configuration changes in the ora2pg.conf file.

In the export section, uncomment the `ALLOW` part and give the needed table names with space or comma(,) separated.

(i.e)

```
ALLOW   CUSTOMER,STUDENT,APPLICATION,EMPLOYEE
```

Then you run the command, the above tables only exported:

```
./export_schema.sh
```

Hope this helps you.